# Como ignorar o persistence.xml no gitignore?

Tags: github, git

Tenho um arquivo de persistencia chamado persistence.xml no caminhos:

> /git/meuRepositorio/MeuProjeto/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

E gostaria de incluí-lo no `.gitignore`, coloquei esse caminho no `.gitignore`, fiz o commit e o push, porém o persistence ainda é visto pelo git, qual forma devo fazer, para que seja ignorado no GIT? 
Lembrando apenas que estou utilizando o `GitHub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa dar um reload no seu .gitgnore que está no Github:

**Primeiro faça qualquer alteração no seu código**, depois execute os seguintes comandos:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Isto remove os arquivos alterados a partir do índice (staging area), em seguida, basta executar:

```
git add .
```

Então faça um commit:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore esta atualizado agora"
```